# REACT: Can't set useState to an array of objects. Console log shows undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am using react and a mongoose/mongo database. On the page loading, I do an API call and receive an array of objects (they are "posts" with titles, descriptions, etc). I am trying to map over the data to dynamically display the post info on separate cards. I can get the data from the API call, but when I try to change state to the array of objects and console log it, I get undefined.

Attached is the photo of the code and result:

[Console log of Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cstpT.png)

[The code of API call (related to pic 1 - please notice the code line numbers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz5v2.png)

Why isn't usestate accepting the change in state from the data? Attached is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import API from "../utils/API"


const Home = () => {

    const [PostObject, setPosts] = useState({
        title: "",
        description: "",
        image: ""
    })

    const [PostList, setList] = useState()


    useEffect(() => {
        retrievePosts()
    }, [])


    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setPosts({ ...PostObject, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }


    const createPost = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setPosts({ ...PostObject, title: "", description: "", image: "" })
        API.addPost(PostObject)
            .then(retrievePosts())
    }


    const retrievePosts = () => {
        API.getPost()
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                setList(res.data)
                console.log(PostList);
            })
    }
```

Comment: `.then(retrievePosts())` should be `.then(retrievePosts)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, corrected the change. Still getting undefined.

Comment: react queue the setState call, so it is not updated immediately, it will update the state and re-render the component so it is painted with the new data

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't usestate accepting the change in state from the data? Attached is my code:

Because you attached an empty dependency array to `useEffect` as in:

```
useEffect(() => {
        retrievePosts()
    }, [])
```

If you pass an empty dependency array, this useEffect will be called only once. If you want to run the `useEffect` after every data change you have to pass the data to the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
            retrievePosts()
        }, [data /*i.e PostList*/])
```

However, be careful not to re-render the component infinite amount of times. You can check libraries like [React-Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) and [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/)

One more thing:

> I can get the data from the API call, but when I try to change state to the array of objects and console log it, I get undefined.

`setState` is an async call. You can't log the data right after calling `setData`. Take a look at [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) article or to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) and see if they help